# Importing CSV to mysql database losing content

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

I have an Excel file (.xlsx format) and I want to import it to my database.

I first saved it in .csv format and I checked spelling because I have some fields with text that is formatted for Romanian language with diacritics and it's OK.

Then I made the table with the column names and imported the table using phpMyAdmin selecting `Character set of the file: utf-8` and the format using `Format: CSV using LOAD DATA`.

It loads fine except I lose all Romanian diacritics and I have a column with text that doesn't import all text, it stops if he finds a Romanian letter ex: (ă,â,î,ș,ț). 
What formatting should i use? for Romanian language is recommended utf-8. 
Edit 1: OK, Wilk helped me with the solution and i think it's this:

```
SET NAMES utf8; 
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/public_html/db/test_db.csv' INTO 
TABLE test_db FIELDS 
TERMINATED BY ';' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

But now i have a new error
 #1045 - Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES).  :)

Comment: The column in the table you made that stores the text has the character set to utf8?

Comment: did you tried `SET NAMES utf8` before doing the `LOAD DATA` ?

Comment: @Stephan yes it's set to store utf8_general_ci

Comment: @Wilq were should i put that?

Comment: @tmanolescu you should execute it before load data in the same mysql session

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`SET NAMES utf8`

Put it in line before `LOAD DATA`

---

Your full SQL should look like:

```
SET NAMES utf8
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE your_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Remember, that `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` operator is your field seperator

Comment: I am using import function from phpMyAdmin, what would be the correct slq?
Something like this?
    SET NAMES utf8
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/temp/testdb/test_db.csv' INTO TABLE `test_db` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

Comment: ok right now my file is on the server in home/public_html/db so the correct path would be:
`SET NAMES utf8
LOAD DATA INFILE 'home/public_html/db/file.csv' INTO TABLE your_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`  ??

Comment: @Wilq y, forgot to put it  sorry :P